# JavaScript: Add sum of even value elements to each odd value element in an given array; show the new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I need to write a code that adds the sum of even value elements to each odd value element in a given array and then show the new array.

Example:

`array = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

Requested sum is `20`. The new generated array should look like:

`array = [2, 23, 4, 25, 27, 8, 29]`

What I have done so far:

```js
let oldArray = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

const sumArray = arr => arr.filter(i => !(i % 2)).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
let newArray = oldArray.map (i => i%2 == 1 + sumArray);

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: `sumArray` is a function, not the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```js
let array = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
console.log(array.map(x=>x%2==0?x:x+array.reduce((a,b)=> a + b*((b+1)%2) )))
```

It's logging an array built on the original array: if the element is even, you leave it that way. If not, you add the sum of the even numbers. How do you do this? You add the element multiplied by the rest of the division of this element added to 1 by 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
let newarray = [];
let sum = 0;
for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
if(array[i]%2 === 0) {
sum += array[i];
}
}
for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
if(array[i]%2 === 0) {
newarray.push(array[i]);
}
else {
newarray.push(array[i]+sum);
}
}
```